# How to add an error page in a .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, error-handling

Below is my `.htaccess` file. I have a `default_rewrite.php` file and I get my content from a database I have created.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9-_]*)$ default-rewrite.php?page=$1 [L]
```

When you go to a known broken link E.G `http://www.example.com/test/fgdhfuis` it goes to my default rewrite page but doesn't go to a page I have stored in the database. E.g

```
http://www.example.com/test/home
```

I have tried `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` but this does not do it for me.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Below the PHP Edit:

```
<?php
  if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
  function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
  {
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
  case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
  case "long":
  case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
  case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
  case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
  case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
  }
  return $theValue;
  }
  }

  $colname_Page = "home";
  if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $colname_Page = $_GET['page'];
  if($colname_Page == "")
  $colname_Page = "home";
  }

  mysql_select_db($database_VRMOnline, $VRMOnline);
  $query_Page = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Page WHERE PageName = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Page, "text"));
  $Page = mysql_query($query_Page, $VRMOnline) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_Page = mysql_fetch_assoc($Page);
  $totalRows_Page = mysql_num_rows($Page);

  mysql_select_db($database_VRMOnline, $VRMOnline);
  $query_MetaData = "SELECT * FROM MetaData WHERE MetaDataID = 1";
  $MetaData = mysql_query($query_MetaData, $VRMOnline) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_MetaData = mysql_fetch_assoc($MetaData);
  $totalRows_MetaData = mysql_num_rows($MetaData);

  ?>
```

I tried

```
  $colname_Page = "home";
  if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $colname_Page = $_GET['page'];
  if($colname_Page == "")
  $colname_Page = "home";
  if ($totalRows_Page == 0)
  {
  $colname_Page = "404-error";
  }
```

But this makes every page go to 404-error

Comment: Is it possible to get the snippet of the code that checks the database? Since your rewrite rule, rewrites all url's to go through default-rewrite.php, the problem will lie in the code.

Comment: So the it goes to the default rewrite page and adds the page from the database.

Comment: There should be another piece of code that checks if $colname_Page exists in the database.

Comment: Then I just add <?php echo $row_Page['PageContent']; ?> to my default rewrite:)

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the code, you could add:

```
if ($totalRows_Page == 0)
{
 // 404 Page Logic
}
```

after the first query, and set colname_Page to equal a 404 page, that you make and put into the database. Or you can send a 404 error in PHP using **header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');** Apache should then use the ErroDocument 404 page that you specified in your .htaccess.

Comment: Simply sending a 404 status (ie. `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found')`) won't magically send the error document as defined in the `ErrorDocument` directive for a 404 error. You would need to manage the 404 document in PHP and send this as part of the response.